# jqPlot Pie chart not rendering correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, charts, jqplot

I am using `jqPlot` in `phonegap` but some problem is there like if I gave static value to `pie chart` then it works well but if I gave dynamic value then not rendering correctly

**Static chart** :-

```
$.jqplot('chartdiv', [ [ [ 'Cricket', 42],
            [ 'Football', 8 ],
            [ 'Basketball', 4 ], [ 'Chess', 28 ],
            [ ' TableTennis', 18 ] ] ], {
        seriesDefaults : {
            renderer : $.jqplot.PieRenderer,
            rendererOptions : {
                showDataLabels : true
            }
        },
        legend : {
            show : true,
            location : 'e'
        }
    });
```

**O/P** :-

[image]

**Dynamic chart** :-

```
var cricketPortion = document.getElementById("value_1").value;
var footballPortion = document.getElementById("value_2").value;
var basketballPortion = document.getElementById("value_3").value;
var chessPortion = document.getElementById("value_4").value;
var ttPortion = document.getElementById("value_5").value;
$.jqplot('chartdiv', [ [ [ 'Cricket', cricketPortion ],
            [ 'Football', footballPortion ],
            [ 'Basketball', basketballPortion ], [ 'Chess', chessPortion ],
            [ ' TableTennis', ttPortion ] ] ], {
        seriesDefaults : {
            renderer : $.jqplot.PieRenderer,
            rendererOptions : {
                showDataLabels : true
            }
        },
        legend : {
            show : true,
            location : 'e'
        }
    });
```

**O/P** :-

[image]

Tell me how can I get rid of this..??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this you will get result

Use `parseInt` for every value

`parseInt(document.getElementById("value_1").value)`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/NYewy/578/)

Comment: Thnx it works but i cant understand, this same scenario works pretty well for Bar chart and Line chart without **parseInt** but in pie chart it creates problem...why..??

Comment: @ldce reason is you are getting string value from element,in order to work we need to convert string to int

Comment: Okay i know that but why string to int conversion only needed in Pie chart rather than Bar chart and Line chart...

Answer (score 0):

Use the `parseInt` function of Javascript to parse the `String` values into `Integers` 
Eg: `parseInt(document.getElementById("value_1").value)`

jqPlot excepts an value(integer) to plot the sections/divisions on the canvas(be it a pie-chart, bar-chart or any other chart)

So its `[ label(a String), value(an Integer) ]` 
Make sure the data-type of the second field is of Integer type

Hope it helps.